# Doing AJAX Post in rails without passing in the authenticity_token

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

So I remember that one time, when i was trying to do an AJAX post, I had to pass in the form_authenticity_token as one of the data to rails. For some reason, not doing so will generate some kind of error and I would get logged out immediately. Is there a way to still have this this authenticity token for form submission but not for ajax post? In other words, I dont want to pass in that autheniticy token in my post data.

Comment: Can you make GET requests using AJAX instead and keep the protect from forgery feature intact?

Comment: If you're using the Rails jQuery UJS adapter (which I'm assuming you are since you tagged jQuery), then it will always submit the authenticity token along with *any* ajax call.  You'd have to modify that JS code to do what you are asking for.  By the way, I hope this is on a website that no one is going to use since this is a bad idea.

Comment: passing in the auth token as a part of ajax is a bad idea? how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than disabling authenticity token verification, you could just pass it to javascript like so:

`<%= javascript_tag "var AUTH_TOKEN = #{form_authenticity_token.inspect};" if protect_against_forgery? %>`

Then just submit `AUTH_TOKEN` along with any AJAX posts.

[Source](http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/05/rails-authenticity-token-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

Per the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

> You can disable csrf protection on controller-by-controller basis:
>
> `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`