# Rails 3.2 POST with AJAX creating MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a bit of a nube, and I am trying to piggyback on bokmann's [rails3_fullcalendar](https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar) to create a calendar app in rails 3.2, but when I try to create an event in my app I get this error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in EventsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, description, starts_at(1i), starts_at(2i),
starts_at(3i), starts_at(4i), starts_at(5i), ends_at(1i), ends_at(2i), ends_at(3i), ends_at(4i),
ends_at(5i), all_day

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"bq3ZUXLm4lYbja9FUafbroFF2Zwt8iMw6GWfvoRuPLA=",
"event"=>{"title"=>"sddfsdf",
"description"=>"df",
"starts_at(1i)"=>"2012",
"starts_at(2i)"=>"6",
"commit"=>"Create Event"}
```

The solution looks like [it should be this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857175/doing-ajax-post-in-rails-without-passing-in-the-authenticity-token) but passing the AUTH_TOKEN with the AJAX POSTs (which it is sending) but it is still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is below, but a better answer is to look at the new version of that demo.  Since the demo you're looking at, I have recreated the demo showing how to do this in Rails 3.2 with the fullcalendar JavaScript and css as an asset gem:

https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar_assets

---

Sometime recently (Rails 3.2?) the defaults for protection against mass assignment were changed...  you now need to specifically allow the attributes that you want to allow mass assignment.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

In the event model, add a line that looks like this:

attr_accessible :title, :description, :starts_at, :ends_at, :all_day

Comment: It worked! now for some reason it generated an entirely new calendar to put the event in! I will rework what little I have with your new demo app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you get this Exception, you should already be authenticated, so the Auth_token is not your problem.

Rails has since version 3.2.3 a default to protect against mass-assignments.
You need to explicitly allow them in the model. That is why older code from third parties will fail. Change the model to:

```
class Event
  ..
  attr_accessible :title, :description, starts_at ...
end
```

But do not include things like `user_id` into the list of allowed attributes, this way you prevent somebody who is only allowed to change her own events to reconnect the event that it will then to belong to another user.

See also the Rails Guide:
[Security Guide, Mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

The fullcalendar app appears to be created before `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` became a rails default.

In your Event model, do you have a line like
`attr_accessible :title, :description` etc.?